# MySql generates files in /var/lib/mysql

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, innodb, database-administration, mysql-5.5

We have noticed that we run out of space on one of our machines that is running Mysql 5.5.37 (InnoDb)

Mysql seems to be generating several ~1.1GB files per day with the name pattern 0.0001234 (increasing number) in the /var/lib/mysql folder.

- What are those files?
- Can they be deleted?
- Can we configure mysql to write them to a different location?

Comment: Looks like these are binary logs.  I wouldnt just delete them if I were you - I'd consult here : https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/purge-binary-logs.html.  I'm sure you can configure them to go elsewhere but I'm not able to find out at present.  Now you know what they are, im sure you can figure it out.  Good luck! :)

Comment: Whats the filename ?

Comment: try: **PURGE BINARY LOGS to 'the last FILENAME' ;** ie. bin-log12345

Comment: thanks, yes we just figured out that these might be binlogs. Our former db admin set log_bin=0 which seems not to disable them but set the name pattern to 0.\\d+

Comment: *PURGE BINARY LOGS* worked. problem solved, thank you!

Comment: Note that purge binary logs is a one-time fix. Refer to Rick's answer below. It's possible to get the files to automatically delete themselves after a number of days. See [expire_logs_days](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/replication-options-binary-log.html#sysvar_expire_logs_days)

Answer (score 4):

To avoid having to do the purge periodically, set this:

```
expire_logs_days = 7
```

in my.cnf.  That will keep the binlogs purged down to 7 days' worth.

See also `binlog_expire_logs_seconds` in MySQL 8.0.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out these were binlogs.

The setting `log_bin=0`
does not disable them but simply sets the file-name-format to 0.\d+

We deleted the present logs with `PURGE BINARY LOGS to 'lastFileName'`, then disabled the generation by commenting out all bin_log related entries in the my.cnf.

Comment: You don't necessarily want to _disable_ them. These logs can be used for [point-in-time recovery](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/point-in-time-recovery.html). And of course they are needed if you want to use [replication](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/replication.html).